# Is there anyway to configure vscode to NOT select the first item from the suggestion list?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm typing "#myDiv ENTER" and I want to get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBd5W.png

But when I type space right after #myDiv, I'm getting this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFrAb.png

Notice that the first item "-moz any()" is seletected. If I press ENTER now, I'll not get my code.

Is there anyway to configure vscode so that it won't select the first item of that list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to your settings.json file to make <kbd>enter</kbd> not accept suggestions.

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": false,
```

You can then only use <kbd>tab</kbd> to accept the suggestions.

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Thank you!